# How to write & and \n together in CDATA android?

Tags: android, xml, cdata

I want to write a string like this way.

**Attach Photos &

Write Comments**

How it is possible to write it in string resources in **Android** with the help of **CDATA**.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution and applied. It works for me.

Just putting the string in string.xml like this way.

```
<string name="dummy">Attach Photos &amp; Write Comments</string>
```